# catalyst request object json input

Tags: json, catalyst

Sample code:

```
sub record_put :Private {
    my ( $self, $c, @args ) = @_;

    $c->log->info( join ', ', %{ $c->request->headers } ) ;
    $c->log->info( $c->request->body ) ;

    $c->response->body( $c->request->body ) ;
}
```

Here's the log data:

```
[info] user-agent, Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/28.0.1500.71 Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36, connection, keep-alive, accept, application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01, accept-language, en-US,en;q=0.8, x-requested-with, XMLHttpRequest, origin, http://localhost:3000, accept-encoding, gzip,deflate,sdch, content-length, 125, host, localhost:3000, ::std_case, HASH(0xaec0ba0), content-type, application/json, referer, http://localhost:3000/test
[info] /tmp/PM2C6FXpcC
```

Here's a snippet of text from the `Catalyst::Request` document:

```
$req->body

Returns the message body of the request, as returned by HTTP::Body: a string, unless Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, text/xml, or multipart/form-data, in which case a File::Temp object is returned.
```

The `File::Temp` manpage does not help.  Even the 'object' overloads its stringification, I can't see how to extract the contents.

Comment: Note that there is no method to obtain the filehandle from the File::Temp object. The object itself acts as a filehandle. The object isa IO::Handle and isa IO::Seekable so all those methods are available.

Comment: Answer was staring me right in the face.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I used:

```
  my $rbody = $c->req->body;
  if ($rbody) {
    # Post requests are stored on the filesystem under certain obscure conditions,                                                                           
    # in which case $rbody is a filehandle pointing to the temporary file      
    if (ref $rbody) {           # a filehandle                                 
      $content = join "", readline($rbody);
      close $rbody;
      unlink "$rbody";  # filehandle stringifies to name of temp file          
    } else {                    # a string                                     
      $content = $rbody;
    }
  }
```

The thing you get back from the `body` method represents a temporary file, and can be treated like a filehandle or like a string.  if you treat it like a filehandle, it reads from the temporary file; if used like a string, its value is the name of the temporary file.  I used the seldom-seen builtin function `readline`, which is the same as the more common `<…>` operator.

I don't expect the `else` path to ever be taken, but it's there defensively, because you never know.

Added 2014-06-09: You need the explicit close; otherwise the code has a file descriptor leak.  Catalyst devs claim that it should be cleaning up the handle automatically, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just trying to parse JSON, the newest stable Catalyst has a method 'body_data' that does this for you (see: http://www.catalystframework.org/calendar/2013/6)